# org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: search_context_missing_exception: No search context found for id

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-spark

Spark tasks are failing because of "No search context found for id". I tried a couple of options like

> spark.es.input.max.docs.per.partition 250
>
> spark.es.scroll.size 100
>
> spark.es.batch.size.bytes 32mb

But tasks are still failing. we are using: 
    **Spark version: 2.3.1,
    Elasticsearh Cluster version: 6.5.4,
    elasticsearch-spark version: 6.5.4**

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: search_context_missing_exception: No search context found for id [4872076]
{"scroll_id":"DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAABKV4wWRTJHQW9CdEZRTHVqMldEWnQxTUJnQQ=="}
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.checkResponse(RestClient.java:443)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:400)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.execute(RestClient.java:382)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.scroll(RestClient.java:458)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.scroll(RestRepository.java:323)
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.ScrollQuery.hasNext(ScrollQuery.java:115)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDDIterator.hasNext(AbstractEsRDDIterator.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1092)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1083)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1018)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1083)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:809)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:347)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:300)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:384)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: I've same error, did you find any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

increasing the value of the below parameter worked for me.

> es.scroll.keepalive=120m (default value is 10m)

reference : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html